# Convert Texture2D to EXR (HDRI)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hdr

I am looking for a way to convert `Texture2D` directly to EXR format in byte array. I've done few research and this seems to be complicated than I thought.

Not really looking for a code since I don't have one. Just a suggestion on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 5.6 just got released and surprisingly, it has the API to perform this Texture2D to EXR conversion.

To convert Texture2D to EXR (HDR)

```
byte []exrBytes  = texture.EncodeToEXR();
```

To convert Texture2D to EXR (HDR) Compressed

```
byte[] exrBytes = texture.EncodeToEXR(Texture2D.EXRFlags.CompressZIP);
```

More EXR encoding flags can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EXRFlags.html).